# Access 2010: Expression to count number of items in a multivalued field

Tags: ms-access, count, multivalue

In Access 2010, I have a table with a multivalued field. On my form, this field is represented as a list where I can check as many values as I want. I want to display the number of selected items. I try using

```
=Count([MyField])
```

but it gives the total number of selected items in all records. How can I get the count of selected items in the current record only?

Comment: can you show the number of selected items in the list?

Comment: Yes, it could be that. I tried to do it, but I didn't find how. I only was able to display the total number of items in the list...

Comment: found this in help: When the MultiSelect property is set to Extended or Simple, you can use the list box's Selected property or ItemsSelected collection to determine the items that are selected.  Charles, the ItemsSelected property has a count property you can use.